# How do I include a Telerik file upload in my MVC3 model binding?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't like to have to use parameters to my POST action methods in addition to my view model parameter.  However, for a file upload using the Telerik Upload helper, it seems I am forced to do this.  The posted value is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`.  Is there any way I can also bind this to the model without the effort of custom model binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't like to have to use parameters
>   to my POST action methods in addition
>   to my view model parameter.

Me neither. That's why I use view models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    if (model.Files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in model.Files)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // process the uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin.  You will notice on close inspection I did say I was using view models, but if the upload is polite about model binding, as you indicate, I must have been doing something wrong for my view model Files property to be null.

Comment: @ProfK, yes, it is possible that you have been doing something wrong. Unfortunately as you haven't shown what exactly you are doing I don't see how I can help you further.

Comment: big oops on my part.  I had the Files property as private in my view model.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the name of the control (Upload().Name(***)) should be the same as model's property.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> ManyFiles { get; set; }
    ...
}
// ...
@Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("ManyFiles")
```

or

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase OneFile { get; set; }
    ...
}
// ...
@Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("OneFile").Multiple(false)
```